# Does right clicking always select the text below the cursor on a mac?

Tags: macos, mouse, contextual-menu

I am pretty new to mac, I am on a desktop mac with a Logitech mouse.

Every time I right click on some text - it selects the word under the cursor.

[image: right click on mouse]

Is this normal? If it is - is there any way to avoid this.
For example - I need to copy the link address in a browser, but when I right click - it selects the text and gives me a different context menu which doesn't have the copy link URL option.

Comment: It is "normal"!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I am using the Firefox.

When I right click on link in a browser it shows this menu

[image]

When I click on text (not link) in browser or any other document it shows the same menu as yours.

When I click on the web address in the address bar it shows the menu with Copy, that I use to cop the link.

Comment: Yep, turns out the link must have a URL, the ones that I was trying to click did not have any URL, they were just styled to look like links.